# What is this rosdep error?

Tags: rosdep, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to get the dependencies for a camera with the following command:
mike@spinach:~/ros_workspace$ rosdep install prosilica_camera

And I get the following error:
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource prosilica_camera
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/mike/ros_workspace
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

What is wrong with my install?

I have run rosdep update.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35741/what-is-this-rosdep-error?/) by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-05**:
What distribution are you using? In Electric, `prosilica_camera` was part of `camera_drivers`. In Fuerte, is belongs to a separate `prosilica_driver` stack.

**Comment by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on 2012-06-05**:
I'm using Fuerte

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-03-20**:
go to `src` directory, where your package reside (don't step in to your package). And try to run this command from there. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specifically this error means that the package prosilica_camera is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

rosdep is a tool for installing system dependencies for source packages.  It does not install the source for you.  You need to check that out from version control.  There are tools like rosinstall which are designed to help with that.  And if you're on Ubuntu usually you can use apt to install most packages, and skip compiling others code from source.

Please make sure to go through the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) to understand the core ROS concepts.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on 2012-06-06**:
Thanks.  I did follow the tutorial, but I think it glances over a simple concept I have no awareness of.  I entered roscd and then rosinstall prosilica_camera and received an error indicating I need to add the location of a ros distribution to this command.  I'm not sure how to do this.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-08-22**:
Your rosinstall link is broken.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-03-20**:
Updated [rosinstall link](https://docs.ros.org/en/independent/api/rosinstall/html/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically you're making this for or inside of a catkin workspace. If that's the case then you need to source the setup.

Steps:

- `$ mkdir -p some_catkin_ws/src`
- `$ cd some_cakint_ws/src`
- `$ catkin_init_workspace`
- `$ cd ..`
- `$ catkin_make`
- `$ source devel/setup.bash`
- add your **prosilica_camera** source to `some_catkin_ws/src`
- `$ rosdep install prosilica_camera`

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4